# How can I use python to edit docx and/or doc file tags on a windows system?

Tags: python-3.x, windows, docx, doc

I have a folder with a large amount of .doc and .docx files, I would like to develop a python script to edit the tags of each file so I can find a file in the folder using the tags - thus making my life a little easier.

I am unsure of how to even start and was hoping someone could point me to a library or provide some sample code to help me get started.

I am not sure if the file extenstion matters because this seems to be a windows property (right-click file > Properties > Details > Tags > type in tags) but if the extension matters I do can change all the files to be .docx

Answer (score 0):

The [python-docx](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) package provides methods to access most of the metatdata in a word file.  The class [docx.opc.coreprops.CoreProperties](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/document.html#coreproperties-objects) in specific allows you to modify author, category, etc.  I didn't see tags mentioned but if you do some more research i'm sure you can find it.

[image: CorePropertiesObjects]

Answer (score 0):

[docx.opc.coreprops.CoreProperties.keywords](https://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/document.html#docx.opc.coreprops.CoreProperties.keywords) can be used to update doc file tags.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: What the community bot is failing to express is that only mentioning/linking something is not considered an answer on StackOverflow. If you link to a description please summarise (not advertise) the solution. If you link to a tool/lib please demonstrate how it can be used to solve the problem.